# Send message to channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having trouble with sending a message to a specific channel, here's the code:

```py
client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def test2():
  channel = client.get_channel(836633672240332820)
  await channel.send('test')
  print('test')

test2.start()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'test2'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 297, in test2
    await channel.send('test')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Any1 able to help?

Comment: This is probably just an issue with the channel ID, since `client.get_channel()` returns `None` if it cannot find a channel with an ID matching the passed integer. Make sure you have the correct ID number.

Comment: I copied multiple times, but I will try another channel. Just for sure.

Comment: Same issue, still not working.

Comment: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2282

Comment: The bot also is able to _see_ the channel, right? Just trying to clear all the minor possibilities out of the way.

Comment: Ill make a quick command to get the channel ID just for sure.

Comment: Also, yes the bot can see every channel.

Comment: Maybe I should make the loop wait for the on_ready function?, Cuz i saw something like that in the site you sent.

One thing,, how?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `get_channel` gets the channel object from the cache, in the first iteration of the loop, the cache is simply not done loading, you can use `Client.wait_until_ready` in the `before_loop` function:

```py
client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def test2():
    channel = client.get_channel(836633672240332820)
    await channel.send('test')

@test2.before_loop
async def before_test2():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

test2.start()
```

If the error persists, make sure you copied the correct channel ID.

#### References:

- [`Client.wait_until_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready)

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `fetch_channel` to fetch the channel directly from the API instead of the cache.

Comment: So i'm not getting an error anymore, thank you. But... it's not sending messages, do I need to start the loop someway?

Comment: Indeed, though you should avoid making API requests as often as possible @12944qwerty

Comment: @ErikN118 Yes, test2.start() should be used as Lukasz shows in his code

Comment: The loop should be started with `test2.start`,  have you started it?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Definitely. But sometimes the error may be caused just because the channel isn't in the cache yet (and the bot started quite some time ago)

Comment: i posted an 'answer' so you can see my code

Comment: That's weird, I tried the code and [works flawlessly](https://streamable.com/m1ai8j) for me. Are you sure you're running the bot? With `client.run("TOKEN")`

Comment: @ErikN118 Try putting a print statement in `on_ready` to make sure that the bot is running.

Comment: yeah no the bot is running

Comment: Try printing something inside the `test2` loop at the beginning of it to make sure that it's actually running.

Comment: did that, the loop isnt running, i really dont know why

Comment: Me neither, I don't think I'll be able to be of more help sadly. If you're starting the task and it's not running I'm unsure what could be wrong.

Comment: @ErikN118 Try putting the start method in `on_ready`

Comment: ill try that now

Comment: Can you paste a link to a pasting website to see the entire code  you're using after this answer?

Comment: do you mean that i should post the file? ill do that

Comment: if ur wondering, yes it's a bot for a taylor swift serv

Comment: also the pasting site did not do a good job with the indentation

Comment: You're starting the task inside a command... Also I send your token to be invalidated as you leaked it. Please regenerate it.

Comment: There's also a few things wrong with your code, you're mixing `client` and `bot`, which you shouldn't. You either `client` or `bot`, not both

Comment: thanks for the token, yeah i just got a msg from discord and i regenerated it

Comment: but the client = discord.Client() and bot = commands.Bot()

Comment: yes, but at the end of the file you're running `bot`, not `client`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232467/discussion-between-erikn118-and-lukasz-kwiecinski).

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a `on_ready` def and put `test2.start()` but that will just loop if you want send it one time put your code in the on_ready

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   test2.start()
```

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  channel = client.get_channel(836633672240332820)
  await channel.send("test")
```